# Setting chef vault variable in template.erb

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a vault item defined as the following in my recipe

```
item = ChefVault::Item.load("user","password")
```

How do i call this this in my `template.erb`? I tried the following which isn't working

```
ROOTPASSWORD= <%= @node["testcookbook"]["user"]["password"] %>
```

My vault item looks like this:

```
$ knife vault show user password
id:       password
pass: xxxxxxxxxx
username: chefuser
```

I generally do something like this within a recipe

```
ROOTPASSWORD #{item['pass']}
```

however I don't think that would work within a template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options to solve that problem though the second one should be preferred as that keeps your sensitive data private.

Suppose, if your vault look like this:

```
knife vault show user password
id:       password
pass: xxxxxxxxxx
username: chefuser
```

Then, you can approach like following:

### Save as Node Attribute

First, if you want to set the password on node object and make it visible, then
you can do something like below:

In recipe:

```
node.default["testcookbook"]["user"]["password"] = ChefVault::Item.load("user","password")['pass']

template '/tmp/template' do
  source 'template.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end
```

In Template:

```
ROOTPASSWORD= <%= node["testcookbook"]["user"]["password"] %>
```

### Pass Data to the Template using `variables`

Second, if you don't want to set the password on node object and let it visible in chef run logs, then you can do something like below:-

```
template '/tmp/template' do
  source 'template.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
  sensitive true
  variables( {:password => ChefVault::Item.load("user","password")['pass']})
end
```

In Template:

```
ROOTPASSWORD= <%= @password %>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it using code. I strongly vote for the second option. If you save it as a node attribute anyways, there's no need to have it in chef-vault.

Comment: Couldn't agree more!

Comment: Good to hear. I suggest to clarify that a bit more in your posting. People might copy&paste that without thinking or reading the discussion below.
Btw. you can indicate your consensus by [upvoting comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work).

Comment: Thank you Mrigesh- I edited the initial question for clarity.

Comment: @jebjeb - Updated the solution.

Comment: Thank you Mrigesh. You solution worked perfectly. I have learned a lot. Thank you once again